# Is there a way to handle abstraction through @Mapping expression

Tags: java, mapstruct

I tried something with mapstruct using abstraction,
it works pretty well apart from one thing.

```
@SubclassMapping(target = SupplierOrderEntity.class, source = SupplierOrderCreateRequest.class)
@SubclassMapping(target = SupplierOrderEntity.class, source = SupplierOrderUpdateRequest.class)
@Mapping(target = "totalQuantity", expression = "java(supplierOrder.sumQuantity())")
@Mapping(target = "weightedAveragePurchasePrice", expression = "java(supplierOrder.getWeightedAveragePurchasePrice() != null ? MathFormat.roundDouble(supplierOrder.getWeightedAveragePurchasePrice(),4): null)")
@BeanMapping(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
SupplierOrderEntity toSupplierOrderEntity(SupplierOrderAbstractRequest supplierOrder);
```

I have one problem in the auto generated method.

```
protected SupplierOrderEntity supplierOrderCreateRequestToSupplierOrderEntity(SupplierOrderCreateRequest supplierOrderCreateRequest) {
        if ( supplierOrderCreateRequest == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        SupplierOrderEntity.SupplierOrderEntityBuilder supplierOrderEntity = SupplierOrderEntity.builder();

        supplierOrderEntity.supplier( blabla( supplierOrderCreateRequest.getSupplier() ) );
        supplierOrderEntity.firstOrderQuantity( supplierOrderCreateRequest.getFirstOrderQuantity() );
        supplierOrderEntity.reapproQuantity( supplierOrderCreateRequest.getReapproQuantity() );
        supplierOrderEntity.alpha3Code( supplierOrderCreateRequest.getAlpha3Code() );
        supplierOrderEntity.currency( supplierOrderCreateRequest.getCurrency() );

        supplierOrderEntity.totalQuantity( supplierOrder.sumQuantity() );
        supplierOrderEntity.weightedAveragePurchasePrice( supplierOrder.getWeightedAveragePurchasePrice() != null ? MathFormat.roundDouble(supplierOrder.getWeightedAveragePurchasePrice(),4): null );

        return supplierOrderEntity.build();
    }
```

As you can see in totalQuantity and weightedAveragePurchasePrice setters, it tries to access through supplierOrder whereas the auto generated method creates a supplierOrderCreateRequest parameter.

Is there a way to handle this specific problem that I don't know ?

Thanks